# How to create "Many to Many" object using template?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, many-to-many

I want to allow user to join one of the listed groups using template. So I found 2 problems here:

1. "Join" button as a form with many to many field.
2. Running python function as a button action in the template. If it's possible I want to run something like this:

   ```
   group.members.add(request.user)
   ```

   and hopefully refresh a page.

**models.py**:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='member')
```

**template.html**:

```
{% for group in groups %}
  <p>{{ group.name }} <button type="submit" action="">Join</button></p>
  <hr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: so you need to create a view function calling `.add()` on the m2m field.

Comment: @ozgur I have a class based view already. That means I should add a function like join_group(group) there? I'm sorry for silly questions, but I'm pretty new to Django.

Comment: Nope you can either create a simple view function or write a separate class based view like `JoinGroupView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing special about a many-to-many field. Anything you want to do anywhere will always require a view. You need a new view with a new URL that is called from your button, and in that view you fetch the object and modify it as necessary.